# KendoUI setting top and left with absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

It seems as though absolute positioning for any Kendo UI control is not working properly. The position, top, and left attrs are applied to the main span that is generated and then cascaded down to the actual input within the kendo control. This results in the input being positioned in absolute positioning within the span that is generated.

This can be seen in this fiddle, which was copied from the kendo dojo:

```
    <div id="example">
        <div id="add-product">
            <div>
                <input id="currency" type="number" value="30" min="0" max="100" style="position:absolute;" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // create Curerncy NumericTextBox from input HTML element
                $("#currency").kendoNumericTextBox({
                    format: "c",
                    decimals: 3
                });

            });
        </script>

    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kckst8/2TJrX/1/

Our application is rendering forms from an xml layout with absolute positioning embedded so it is required.

Thoughts or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to have the `input` with `absolute` positioning? What about having its container with absolute?

I.e. Instead of:

```
<div id="add-product">
    <div>
        <input id="currency" type="number" value="30" min="0" max="100" style="position:absolute;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

do

```
<div id="add-product">
    <div style="position:absolute;">
        <input id="currency" type="number" value="30" min="0" max="100"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2TJrX/2/

Comment: yes, this is a valid workaround and it is the best answer at this point. We are attempting to use kendo ui controls in a generic form builder service that already creates inputs with positioning. Wrapping them in an extra div will require modifications to that really should not be needed, but until it is resolved by telerik it seems like the only way to go unless we abandon Kendo altogether...thanks for the response!

Comment: You should keep in mind that KendoUI uses to "translate" your `input` element in one or more HTML elements. This is done in order to guarantee that it is displayed the same no matter the browser (as much as possible). So, working with the original HTML element uses to be _tricky_ since sometimes it is even hidden behind some other HTML element that emulates the same behavior.